# "as befits" or "as befit"

Tags: verb-agreement, conjunctions, verb-phrases

Consider these sentences, please:

1. He writes beautifully, **as befits** a poet.
2. She was buried in the cathedral, **as befits** someone of her position.
3. **As befits** a Quaker, he was a humane man.

These are sentences taken from different dictionaries. As we can see, all of them use the phrase "as befits."

Q: As it is clear from the above examples that the verb "befit" in the phrase "as befit(s)" does not have a visible semantic subject. So, Is it always "as befit**s**", using the singular form of the verb, or do we use "as befit", using the plural form, in some contexts?

Comment: ' ... as is fitting for [such a person]' _not_ ' ... as are fitting for'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Befit* means *be appropriate for.* There is an unspoken subject, *it*, which is always singular.

> It befits a poet to write beautifully.

Answer (score 1):

A little reconstruction may reveal what is going on:

Beautiful writing befits a poet

Cathedral burial befits her

Humaneness befits a Quaker

Hence we may use the plural form to write:

Nobility and courage befit admiration as a hero.

When turned round to mimic the structure of your examples:

As befit nobility and courage, they are admired as heroic qualities.